# Is it possible to securely add an NFSv4 share to an ESXi Server?

Tags: security, vmware-esxi, nfs, kerberos, vmware-vcenter

I just wondered how to connect an NFSv4 share as storage extension to my ESXi. Since NFSv4 supports Kerberos, ESXi could use Username and Password to connect to the share, while no one else could access the data. But it seems VMware does not support that?! Without authentication it's completely worthless. Anyone in the LAN could get the NFS Share Export List and then fake it's IP to get access to the storage.

Is there really no way to use NFSv4 + Kerberos with ESXi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to make this work at present. ESXi only supports NFS v3.